# Dota 2: increase Viewport size

Tags: dota-2

Is there a way to increase the viewport using configs or video.txt?
It seems that the viewport depends on monitor resolution, but I heard that resolution does not matter and everyone has the same viewport.

Comment: Not possible without modifying core game files, which will probably get your account banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is fixed for everyone and doing so might get you flagged as a cheater

Blizzard did that on some players of Diablo 3 ([Diablo III Accounts Banned](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6469730/Diablo_III_Accounts_Banned-08_11_2012))

Comment: Except that Dota 2 has nothing to do with Blizzard, the answer is correct. Modifying viewport will give you an unjustified advantage and it will probably cause a ban by Valve.